# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library php_mysql.dll, Mac 10.6, Apache 2.2, php 5.3.0

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to use the PHP CLI, and when I enter something like `php test.php` in the command line it returns:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/php_mysql.dll' - dlopen(/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/php_mysql.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0 
something
```

`test.php` contains:

```
<?php
echo 'something';
?>
```

I checked `/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/`, and as expected the .dll file isn't there. I'm a complete beginner when it comes to this - what is happening, and how can I fix it? A search of my system for "php_msyql.dll" reveals nothing. Does it have to do with how I compiled it? I don't have the original version of php that came with the mac, I think - I may have reinstalled it somewhere along the way.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This should be on serverfault.com

Comment: What OS are you using? Windows or Linux?

Comment: Maybe not your problem (yet), but AFAIK .dlls are always WIndows compiled libraries. The default extension for extensions in the Linux/Unix/OSX world is .so

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On Mac you should not deal with dll files as these are Windows libraries. You should check your **php.ini** file for any uncommented (no semicolon in front) lines like **extension=** under Dynamic Extensions section and make sure that all those lines are commented.
Btw to find location of php.ini file type in Terminal:

```
$php --ini
```

And it will give you something self-explanatory like:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File: /private/etc/php.ini
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about new account, (munchybunch here, dunno how to deal with the OpenID stuff) but I'm using Mac OS X Snow Leopard. I thought the .dll was weird too, and in that folder right now there's phpcups.so. I'm just confused as to what's causing it to look for the dll file. Is there a script being called somewhere trying to load it?